# Search the same number cell in column and paste the values in other location

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have attched the image here with please find that, in that i want to place 1 to 4 values in first column the values of 1 to four serch and paste indivially to other location.
If i search 1 the values of 1 ex 50,5 and more
if i search 2 then values of 2.
help i am new to excel vba

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems you have misunderstood the purpose of this site. Please take a minute to take the [tour], and another five to read the [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following ***ARRAY*** formula in `G3` cell then drag and down and right.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$12=$G$1,ROW($B$1:$B$12),""),ROW(1:1)),COLUMNS($A$1:B$1)),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

`---------------------------------- Edit -----------------------------`

Put value 1,2,3 or 4 in `G1` first then run the macro

```
        Sub CopyFilterData()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set filterRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
        Set copyRange = Sheet1.Range("A2:C" & lastRow)

          filterRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("G1").Value
           copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("F3")
            Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
            Columns("F:F").Select
          Selection.ClearContents
        Range("G1").Select

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Again, you must press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after typing formula, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I  WANT RUN IT AS VBA CODE, PLEASE SEND ME CODE, FORMULA NOT NEEDED

Comment: @MahanteshAmbole, please read carefully Mat's Mug's comment under your question

Comment: Yeh ! it works I am happy !!!!Thank you

Comment: @MahanteshAmbole Glad it works. You should accept my answer. Tick my answer as green.

Comment: Please help one more, If i put value other than range it causes error can you please suggest me what to do that case ?

Comment: @harun24hr You are the definition of altruism and patience, lol